# Comparing estimates of Ripley's K function using Matlab and R

Tags: r, matlab, statistics, spatstat, stochastic-process

I am using the following Matlab code to estimate Ripley's K function.

```
a = 0;
b = 50;
C_x = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1);
C_y = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1);

locs = zeros(length(C_x),2);
locs(:,1) = C_x;
locs(:,2) = C_y;

dist = a:1:b;
K_t = RipleysK(locs, dist, [a, b, a, b]);
plot(dist,K_t);
title('$\hat{K}$ function','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',14);
xlabel('$r$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',14);
ylabel('$\hat{K}(r)$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',14);
csvwrite('test.csv',locs);
```

"RipleysK" function can be found at:
http://www.colorado.edu/geography/class_homepages/geog_4023_s07/labs/lab10/RipleysK.m

In comparison, I am using the following R script.

```
mydata <- read.csv("test.csv",header=F)
mydata
w <- owin(xrange = c(0,50),yrange = c(0,50))
pp <- as.ppp(mydata,w)
K <- Kest(pp,correction = "none")
plot(K)
```

Matlab estimates K for specified values of r (i.e., dist) whereas R script does not (estimates till r = 12.5).

Can somebody comment please? Which one is correct? Can we specify r values in R script?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read [`?Kest`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/spatstat/docs/Kest)?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, yes skimmed through R code. I have one observation that Kest estimates K function for r = n/4 e.g., 50/4 = 12.5 which is same as done in Matlab code. They have similar estimates. Now I just wanted to know that whether we can access K values of Kest in R plot (in a similar way we use data tips in Matlab graph) or we can not do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not looked the matlab code, but I'm very certain that `Kest` in the `spatstat` package calculates the right thing. From your own comment it also appears that there is no conflict in this -- they just do two different things: The matlab code evaluates an estimate of the K-function for one specific value of r while `Kest` does it for a range of r-values (and it also calculates a collection of different estimators). By default it calculates the estimates for 513 values of r, and the easiest way to see them all is to covert to a `data.frame` (continuing your code):

```
Kdf <- as.data.frame(K)
head(Kdf)
```

Alternatively you can convert the function value (`fv`) object `K` to a normal R function and evaluate that at the relevant value of r (this automatically chooses the "best" estimator among the available ones (typically Ripley's isotrotically corrected estimator)):

```
Kf <- as.function(K)
Kf(12.5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and add-on. It really worked as I wanted.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Maybe you would consider accepting the answer so it doesn't show up as unanswered in searches?